# Threads are not being detached

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am trying to make a thread pool. I have an `std::unordered_map` which maps thread ids to `std::thread`s (`workers`). The thread ids are the ids of the threads waiting for a task to be pushed into the thread pool (`waiters`). The tasks are represented by a `std::stack` (`tasks`). Once a task is pushed into the pool, the task is popped from the stack and made into a thread function as the "value" part of the map.

In the destructor I try to detach all the threads that are still running. But I still get the following exception:

```c++
terminate called without an active exception
bash: line 7: 16881 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./a.out
```

This means the threads weren't detached and the program terminated. But my destructor goes through the elements and detaches them (I believe). Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

```c++
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <condition_variable>

template <class F>
class thread_pool
{
    static_assert(std::is_function<F>::value, "F must have function type");
public:
    thread_pool();
    ~thread_pool();
    template <class Task>
    void push(Task&&);
private:
    std::unordered_map<std::thread::id, std::thread> workers;
    std::queue<std::thread> waiters;
    std::stack<std::function<F>> tasks;
    static std::size_t max;
private:
    std::condition_variable m_cond;
    std::mutex m;
private:
    void wait_for_tasks();
};

template <class F>
std::size_t thread_pool<F>::max(10);

template <class F>
thread_pool<F>::thread_pool()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < max; ++i)
        waiters.emplace(&thread_pool<F>::wait_for_tasks, this);
}

template <class F>
void thread_pool<F>::wait_for_tasks()
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
        m_cond.wait(lock, [this] { return !tasks.empty(); });

        auto f = tasks.top();
        tasks.pop();
        auto& th = workers[std::this_thread::get_id()];

        if (th.get_id() == std::thread::id())
            th = std::thread(f);
    }
}

template <class F>
template <class Task>
void thread_pool<F>::push(Task&& t)
{
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
        tasks.emplace(std::forward<Task>(t));
    }
    m_cond.notify_all();
}

template <class F>
thread_pool<F>::~thread_pool()
{
    std::for_each(workers.begin(), workers.end(), [] (std::pair<std::thread::id const, std::thread>& p)
    {
        if (p.second.joinable())
            p.second.detach();
    });

    while (!waiters.empty())
    {
        auto& t = waiters.front();
        waiters.pop();
        if (t.joinable())
            t.detach();
    }
}

int main()
{
    thread_pool<void ()> pool;
}
```

I'm not even sure this is the best way to do it, this is my first time making one. [Here is a demo.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aab488ea1ee06024)

Comment: I concur with quantdev's answer, but I'm genuinely curious what this is trying to accomplish that a simple vector of `std::thread`, a queue, and a traditional notify-to-exit-then-join approach wouldn't solve. You obviously know your needs better than we, but simple is usually.. well.. simpler. Interesting model, none-the-less.

Comment: @WhozCraig I have a hard time using a vector of threads. The threads are first supposed to be waiting for a task to enter the queue, and then how do I turn a thread from a waiting thread to a thread that does the task? Also, how does the notify-to-exit-then-join approach work?

Comment: It would be difficult to model in comments. If I have the opportunity in the next day or two I'll see if I can piece a trivial model together, but a little hunting on pthreads, work queue pools, and condition variables would likely yield what I would type up. I quick peek at your SO-history leaves me no doubt you'll *easily* understand.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks, I will look those things up. BTW isn't pthreads largely unneeded in C++11 due to the standard library's multithreading support? Why do I need to use that?

Comment: It is indeed what you should use. Most non windows platforms will use pthreads behind the scenes. <thread> etc is closely modeled as such. Understanding pthread concepts certainly helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your pool destructor, you are calling `pop` *before* detaching the thread, effectively destructing a thread that is joinable : the standard guarantees that this will call [`std::terminate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate)

First detach the thread, and *then* pop it out of the queue :

```
while (!waiters.empty())
{
    auto& t = waiters.front();

    if (t.joinable())
        t.detach();

    waiters.pop();
}
```